# Using reflection to determine if a control supports an event

Tags: vb.net, reflection

To avoid the try-catch block, is there a way to determine if a control supports the specified event without having a try-catch block?

```
Dim d As [Delegate] = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(eventHandler.EventHandlerType, _
                                                                Me, _
                                                                "OnControlValueChanged") '<<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reflection:

```
Dim events As System.Reflection.EventInfo() = GetType(Control).GetEvents()
For Each someEvent As System.Reflection.EventInfo In events
    If someEvent.Name = "OnControlValueChanged" Then
        'Do what you need to do
    End If
Next
```